# Can Firefox be forced to use ssl instead of tls

Tags: ssl, firefox, https, tls1.2, csr

I would like to force firefox 56 to use ssl instead of tls1.2 despite that [SSL 3.0 is considered unsafe](http://kb.mozillazine.org/SSL_is_disabled).
My intend is to produce an error like `...no overlap ...`.  and take a screenshot of this error.

#### Preferences in about:config

According to my understanding of the [firefox docs for `security.tls.version*`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*) I have set

- `security.tls.version.min = 0` and
- `security.tls.version.max = 1`

The docs for `security.tls.version*` also point out:

> These preferences replace the deprecated `security.enable_ssl3` and
> `security.enable_tls` boolean settings. Upon upgrade, the old
> preferences are not automatically migrated.

So i checked if deprecated preference might be in conflict with my settings above. But my Firefox 56 installation has no preferences that start with `security.enable_`. So it seems that i do not have to worry about any deprecated settings.

Additional causes might be

- that [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade-Insecure-Requests?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=devtools-netmonitor&utm_campaign=default) interferes with my intent to use ssl3,
- that the [rc4 cipher was planned to be removed](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/09/11/deprecating-the-rc4-cipher/) and [`security.tls.unrestricted_rc4_fallback` was removed in Firefox 50](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1153050) and can no longer be overridden.

#### Is the certificate the cause

The website uses a certificate that has these characteristics:

> The connection to this site uses a strong protocol (TLS 1.2), an
> obsolete key exchange (RSA), and an obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with
> HMAC-SHA1).

After reading [this reply](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/70842/60078) i assumed that the cipher used is not part of TLSV1 but running the command below seem to prove that the cipher used is a SSL3 supported cipher.

```
openssl ciphers -v 'TLSv1' | grep "AES" | grep "256" | grep "CBC" | sort
// output
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

### Update

#### HSTS - Strict-Transport-Security HTTP response header field

This question [Is firefox disabling of insecure TLS fallback part of the HSTS spec](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111447/) might be related.

The [HTTP Strict Transport Security chapter 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-5.1) (HSTS - rfc 6797) contains

> An HTTP host declares itself an HSTS Host by issuing to UAs an HSTS
> Policy, which is represented by and conveyed via the
> Strict-Transport-Security HTTP response header field over secure
> transport

The site in question has these header fields among others

```
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
cache-control: max-age=315360000, public
expires: Sat, 03 Jul 2027 00:48:12 GMT
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

#### Questions (tl;dr)

1. It seems that firefox from version 50 on and above can not be forced to use ssl3. Is this the case? If not how can it be achieved?
2. To my understanding the [certificate signing request (CSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) is the first step to get a certificate. Does the CSR already contain the ciphers and protocols that must be used in a https-connection later?

See also

- [Firefox Error_loading_secure_sites page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Error_loading_secure_sites)

Comment: I downloaded firefox esr portable 45.8 - but it seems that does not help as well. This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/42tzbh/is_securitytlsinsecure_fallback_hosts_deprecated/?st=j4q9uv6p&sh=e505d9f8)  suggest to go back as long as version 30 from firefox.

Comment: P3P values https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zh/SSPREK_7.0.0.1/com.ibm.isam.doc_80/ameb_webseal_guide/concept/con_dflt_plcy_p3p.html

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? You have given an X-Y Problem question (see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.`. I think this is not the case - my actual problem is "how can i to produce an error like ...no overlap ....". I want to take a screenshot what a user sees if he has an older browser that does not support tls 1.2: Desktop IE9, IE10 capable under Windows 7 or newer, but not by default. Windows Vista, XP  and older operating not compatible with TLS 1.2 
Desktop IE8 and below: Not compatible or stable with TLS 1.2 [source](https://qsportal.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOC/TLSv1.2+Browser+Compatibility)

Comment: Why? No one using Firefox 56 will ever get that scenario.

Comment: I agree; i just found out that [msft provides a vm with win7 and ie8](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) but at the time of asking i was not aware of it; so setting up a test environment with win7 + ie8 seemed to time consuming therefore i did choose to use firefox instead.

Comment: I still do not understand WHAT you are trying to achieve. Is it to know what an SSLv3 client will do when it tries to connect to a server which only supports TLSv1 and above? If so what does the error message matter? Especially the error message from a future version which definitely DOES support TLSv1 and TLSv1.2 - the error message may have changed. That is why it is an XY problem. You are asking for help with your solution (which may not be the correct way of doing this) without explaining the problem (which may have a simpler problem - E.g. why not make the server support SSLv3 only?).

Comment: The server only uses TLS 1.2; older browsers that are not capable of TLS 1.2 can not communicate with the server and therefore this older browsers can not render the page. I wanted to make a screenshot, document what these old browsers display to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I understand so the reason you want to enable SSL in Firefox is to take a screenshot so if you turn this off, you will see the type of error message and be able to explain the problem to the user? I would suggest this is not a constructive use of your time.

Firefox disabled [SSLv3 by default in Firefox 34](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/34.0/releasenotes/) - which was over 20 versions ago (though admittedly only 3 years ago) at the time of writing. So even if you could somehow re-enable it in the current version, the error message might be completely different as to what was in that version.

So, if you really want to do this, then you are much better checking the version of the browser that did support that, rather than trying to hack the current version. If you do not have access to old browsers then a site like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live) can help with this. But even then it could change depending on which version users are using.

Additionally Firefox has supported TLSv1.0 from the start, so you really don't need to be worried about turning off SSLv3, at least for your Firefox users. Perhaps you need to be worried about turning off TLSv1.0 as [TLSv1.2 was only enabled in version 27 (released in February 2014)](http://caniuse.com/#search=TLS%201.2), and we'll get to that in a bit, but I really wouldn't worry about disabling SSLv3 for your Firefox users.

In fact ALL browsers in use today support TLSv1.0 ([handy chart here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220586&language=en_US&type=1)), and any browser that doesn't will likely have much bigger problems with most websites unless they really are just plaintext sites or you are really, really good a progressive enhancements.

So turn off SSLv3 - [it's insecure and should not be used](http://disablessl3.com/). The alternative is to risk 100% of your users for the vast minority who are using ancient browsers. Yes browsers should use the highest version of TLS rather than SSL if they support it but various downgrade attacks can inadvertently cause this not to be the case. The safest option is to just disable it. I'm not normally one to go in for absolutes, and would normally suggest you measure your usage but for the vast majority of sites disabling SSLv3 is something they should do. Even [Google has disabled SSLv3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.google.com&s=172.217.6.36&hideResults=on&ignoreMismatch=on) for their site and if they can do that, then you can be sure it's safe for you to do it.

Should you get complaints then the error message will likely say something along the lines of "Secure Connection Failed" with protocol error. https://badssl.com/ is a very handy website for testing bad SSL/TLS config, though unfortunately it does not have an example for SSLv3.

Next up will be switching off TLSv1.0 and it will be less easy as it took browsers a lot longer to implement the later versions (particularly Internet Explorer who didn't get TLSv1.2 reliably until version 11). TLSv1.0 is not broken yet, but is on it's way out and standards like PCI-DSS are mandating it be switched off soon (though [they've pushed back on the date for this at least once](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/migrating-from-ssl-and-early-tls)). If you want to test this in firefox this is easy by setting `security.tls.version.max = 1` and visiting a TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 only site like https://tfl.gov.uk/ where you see the following message (which is probably similar to what your SSLv3 visitors would see rather than the cipher error you have shown in your answer):

> An error occurred during a connection to tfl.gov.uk. Peer reports
>   incompatible or unsupported protocol version. Error code:
>   SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT

[image: Firefox TLSv1.2 error]

I would also suggest you add logging to your webserver logs to track the TLS version used so you can make future decisions on when to turn protocols or ciphers off. This is fairly easy with [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/620123/how-can-i-let-nginx-log-the-used-ssl-tls-protocol-and-ciphersuite) and [Apache](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Logging+SSL/18847) for example, though if using other web servers, or if you a load balancer in front of your webserver that handles your TLS, then need to see if they allow this.

Finally to answer your second question, no the CSR does not define the protocol nor the ciphers used. That is decided by a combination of what the server and client both support. Ideally the server should enforce more secure protocols and ciphers in preference to weak ones.

The protocol (SSLv3, TLSv1.0...etc.) is how the HTTPS connection is made, and how the cipher is decided. The cipher is what is used to actually encrypt the connection. As such ciphers are not limited to the protocol that they were originally introduced for and PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA for example is available whether you are using SSLv3, TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. TLSv1.3 (soon to be released) is the first version that has tried to actively remove old ciphers rather than just continue to expand the list.

For some time now Chrome has given a mild warning for older cipher suites (basically those not using GCM in the cipher suite names though there are a few less common ones that it also considers secure), which is why you see the "The connection to this site uses... an obsolete key exchange (RSA), and an obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1)." message. The [SSLLabs Server Test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) is the best tool for checking your server set up and I would suggest comparing it to other sites to get an A grade which should stand you in good stead for some time (I suggest rescanning quarterly to keep up with any changes in the security world - for example like SSLv3 being found to be insecure). Mozilla also have a very handy [SSL/TLS config generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) for the most common browsers.

HSTS (or HTTP Strict Transport Security) has no barring on this conversation really. It simply states that the client MUST use HTTPS for the site and should not use plain HTTP. That off course depends on being able to make a secure HTTPS connection. This can be a dangerous option to turn on if some of your site or domain has not been ported to HTTPS yet.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, the hint to log tls details and links. 
`Side-notes:` A few users still use old browsers (IE8 for instance). Our admins have set up a policy that forces us to use TLS 1.2 only. So i am unable to offer anything below TLS 1.2. I thought that the server was configured to use HSTS as well; but the chrome-network-tab did not reveal a field `Strict-Transport-Security` in the header.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for Question 1: Force firefox to use a weak encryption

I was unable to force a current firefox (v 54) to use a weak encryption. As [this reddit thread suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/42tzbh/is_securitytlsinsecure_fallback_hosts_deprecated/?st=j4q9uv6p&sh=e505d9f8) i downloaded [Firefox 30.0 portable from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2030.0/) and after setting `security.tls.version.max = 1` was able to force the desired error `Firefox Secure connection failed: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap`

This is the screenshot i was after:

[image: Firefox Secure connection failed: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap]

### Question 2: Does the CSR already contain the ciphers and protocols that must be used?

This is still unclear to me.

Comment: No a CSR only contains the information needed to create the certificate. The ciphers and protocols are decided by the server and client and the same certificate can be used for SSLv3 or TLSv1.2 and similar for ciphers depending on the server set up and the client used. Your warning is because your server is set up for older ciphers. Google your server and https setup to improve this (e.g. Google "Apache https setup" if using Apache).

Comment: Are you sure that the cause it the server using older ciphers?
 I assume the warning in this case occurs because i forced an older firefox to accept at max tls 1.1; the server is set up to communicate only with tls 1.2 therefore there is no overlap.

Comment: I was talking about your Chrome warning in the first question. There it made the connection but warned you that you were using an older cipher and should be using better ones.